# schtasks.exe adding repeat every 10 min when not desired

Tags: windows, scheduled-task, task-scheduler, schtasks

I am trying to create a scheduled task from the command line.  I need the task to run every day at 7:05pm and run for a maximum duration of 1 hour.  Just once until the next day.

Here is my command:

```
schtasks.exe /create /ru DeployUser /rp '********' /tn "Run All Tasks" /tr "'tasks.exe RunAllTasks'" /sc DAILY /st 19:05:00 /F /du 01:00
```

That command produces the following trigger.

> At 7:05 PM every day - After triggered, repeat every 10 minutes for a duration of 1 hour.

The repeating every 10 minutes is not desirable and I do not see where in my command this was requested.  Maybe it is a default for using duration, is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: It would have been nice if there was the option of cron syntax

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem here.  I've found it is a default setting when you use either the /ET or /DU switch.

Frustratingly I haven't yet figured out how to stop the repeat applying when using either of the switches.

Here's the bit from the technet that I found it in:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_change

> /ri Specifies the repetition interval in minutes. This is not
>   applicable for schedule types: MINUTE, HOURLY, ONSTART, ONLOGON, and
>   ONIDLE. Valid range is 1 to 599940 minutes (599940 minutes = 9999
>   hours). ***If either /ET or /DU is specified, then the repetition
>   interval defaults to 10 minutes.***

Doesn't answer the question but hopefully provides a bit of clarity.

The closest suggestion I've found to an answer is to create a second task that ends the first one: schtasks /end /tn *TaskName*

Answer (score 1):

To suppress repeat period - use key "/ri 0"

Answer (score 0):

From [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_change):

> ***/ri <Interval>***
>
> Specifies the repetition interval in minutes. This is not applicable for schedule types: MINUTE, HOURLY, ONSTART, ONLOGON, and ONIDLE. Valid range is 1 to 599940 minutes (599940 minutes = 9999 hours). If either /ET or /DU is specified, then the repetition interval defaults to 10 minutes.

You should add `/ri` of 24 hours (`/ri 1440`). The wording of the quote implies that you can change the repeat interval from the default with `/ri`.

Comment: how will daylight savings time affect this setting?  I used /sc DAILY to assure I run at a specific time 7:05PM but with /ri 1440 it seems the run time would change from 7:05PM to 8:05PM (or 6:05PM) depending on when i initiate the task setup.  Am I wrong with this assumption?